# Ошибка соединения. Программа не хочет запускаться

Tags: c#

Возникла трудность. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проектом.
Имеется проект и база данных .sql

Как правильно присоединить для работы? Т.е. присоединить БД .sql для работы ЭТОГО проекта.
Как правильно запустить. Буду рада если кто-то даст ответ-инструкцию.. Ну очень надо. Буду премного благодарна! Проект не сложный.. как для вас.

Проект по ссылке: https://dropmefiles.com/3qAs0

**P.S.** Строго не судите.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'При установлении соединения с SQL
> Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным
> экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя
> экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные
> соединения. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Не удалось
> открыть подключение к SQL Server)'

Строка которая отвечает за подключение видимо:

```
 private User CurrentUser; // Текущий пользователь
        private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; // Строка для подключения
```

У меня установлена на моем компьютере - SQL Server 2012 на ОС Windows 10.
Как подключить вопрос? База данных формата .sql. База данных .sql находится в той же папке что и программа.

Comment: Нужно задать правильную строку соединения. Всё! Какую именно строку задать - никто со стороны не сможет вам сказать. Это нужно знать, какой именно сервер вы используете, где разворачиваете приложение.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, SQL Server. Развернуть нужно на Windows 10\7. Можете посмотреть пожалуйста, где эта строка. Я вот смотрела и что-то не нахожу такого(

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, Проект по ссылке: https://dropmefiles.com/3qAs0 Может кто помочь разобраться?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, я нашла. private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; // Строка для подключения. Как её изменить. Чтобы можно было использовать т.е. подключится?

Comment: Сама строка задана в конфиге, под именем "DefaultConnection". Приведите её. / Повторяю: никто не знает, где и как вы разворачиваете свою программу. Есть ли там установленный Sql Server и прочее.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, у меня установлена на моем компьютере - SQL Server 2012 на ОС Windows 10. Я нашла и перевела, что значит. Как подключить вопрос? База данных формата .sql. Можете подсказать? Проект  dropmefiles.com/3qAs0

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, база данных .sql находится в той же папке что и программа.

Comment: Вся необходимая информация должна содержаться в вопросе. Отредактируйте его. Не пишите в комментариях.